# Напечатать на принтере цветной текст с предварительным просмотром (C#, WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, парсер, печать

**1-й вариант: (Библиотеку для работы с документами Word использовать нельзя)**
Есть документ Microsoft Word. В основном текст черный, но есть некоторые слова или предложения, которые необходимо печатать, например, красным цветом, другие жирным шрифтом. Т.к. таких слов немного, я ставлю метки, примерно таким образом: *...Обычный текст #выделить красным# @выделить жирным@ обычный текст...*.

Делаю так: Копирую, вставляю текст с метками из Word в текстовый документ. Далее помещаю его в строку. Прошу помощи, не могу найти оптимального решения, ткните носом в каком направлении двигаться. Понимаю, что, скорее всего, надо парсить строку, возможно, заносить ее по частям в массив строк, но ума не приложу как дальше быть. Ведь при печати нужно указывать позицию начала печати...

**2-й вариант: (С использованием библиотеки)**
На ПК, где будет установлена программа нет и не будет Microsoft Word. Есть ли возможность заранее добавить Word-овские документы в ресурсы программы и выводить их в цветную печать как есть?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Библиотеку для работы с документами Word использовать нельзя. - почему?

Comment: @PashaPash, такая поставлена задача. Хотя это можно обсудить, если существует более простое решение с использованием библиотеки. Тогда вопрос такой: будет ли работать программа с библиотекой для Word на ПК без установленного Word-a? И можно ли заранее добавить в программу word-овские файлы, например, в ресурсы?

Comment: Да, стандартный OpenXML SDK работает с docx файлами без word. да, можно добавить word файлы как ресурсы.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Comment: Но вот печатать родными средствами без word не получится

Comment: @PashaPash, тогда этот вариант не подходит. Нужно печатать без установленного Word-а